Where can I find a readable theme for Gimp
Where can I find some readable themes for Gimp?
The ones supplied by Gimp are "Gothic" and hard to read for older folks.
Thanks.

Try here: https://www.gnome-look.org/browse?cat=268
Otherwise Gimp comes with a "Light" theme and a "Color" icon theme:

